# How to Restrict a Student in MERN to mark his Attendence only once a day If he marks his Attendence again for the second time he should get an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mern

I am making Student Attendence System in MERN Stack and for that I am making an API in Nodejs/Express.js that will mark the attendence of a user . I am having a problem that how can I implement that Student can mark his Attendence only once a day If he is marking his attendence second time in the same day he should get an error. This is the API that  I have written

```
export const setAttendence = async (req, res, next) => {

    const newAttendence = new Attendence({
      user: req.user.id,
      isPresent: req.body.isPresent,
    });
    try {
      const savedAttendence = await newAttendence.save();
      res.status(200).json(savedAttendence);
    } catch (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
};
```

I am making an API in Nodejs/Express.js/MongoDB that will mark the attendence of a user . I am having a problem that how can I implement that Student can mark his Attendence only once a day If he is marking his attendence second time in the same day he should get an error

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there exists already an entry for that particular user for that day and proceed further. For example,

```
export const setAttendence = async (req, res, next) => {

    const __attendence = await Attendence.findOne({user: req.user.id});
    if(__attendence) return res.status(400).send("Your attendence is already marked!");
    //add above two lines

    const newAttendence = new Attendence({
      user: req.user.id,
      isPresent: req.body.isPresent,
    });
    try {
      const savedAttendence = await newAttendence.save();
      res.status(200).json(savedAttendence);
    } catch (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
};
```

You would need to add the logic to check for the particular day as it is not present in the code snippet given by you.